# What is the magical wasp that Newt notices several times in New York City?

Tags: plot-explanation, fantastic-beasts, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

In *Fantastic Beasts And Where To Find Them*, after arriving in New York City (and I think only after his collection of magical creatures escapes his suitcase), Newt Scamander notices a bright blue insect that looks a bit like a wasp, several times. What is this thing, and does it have any significance in the plot? Is it a local creature that he longs to capture and study, or something he had inadvertently brought with him?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's apparently a beetle called a **Billywig**. [This Insider](http://www.thisisinsider.com/creatures-in-fantastic-beasts-2016-11/#several-times-throughout-the-film-we-see-a-blue-beetle-flying-through-the-city-called-a-billywig-7) piece describes it. Here is an extract from there:

> The sapphire blue insect has a stinger and wings on its head that let it spin while it flies. People stung by Billywigs may levitate while having a mild case of giddiness.

I don't recall seeing it come out of the Newt's case, but I am thinking it is not local to NYC because people don't seem to be levitating there for no apparent reason. I think Newt longs to closely study all magical creatures, so I would think the billywig is included.

Comment: Is the insider an official source?

Comment: I would not characterize it as such. But I would say it has a lot of information that many people can find useful.

Comment: OK, I found it here at Pottermore, which is certainly an official source: https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/billywigs. I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's a [Billywig](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Billywig). He brought it with him and it escaped from his case. Strangely, they never show him recapturing it, or explain what happened to it.